# Multiprocessing Pool gets successively slower after multiple calls

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, random-forest

I want to iteratively train 1000 random forests on a dataset. To speed things up, I'm trying to utilize multiple cores during the iterated training loop. An working example is below:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from multiprocessing import Pool,cpu_count
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import time

n = 2000
ndims = 5000

X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,1,n*ndims).reshape((n,ndims)))
y = pd.Series(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(n)))


def draw_batches(n,size=100):
    steps = np.arange(0,n,size)
    if not n%size == 0:
        steps = np.append(steps,n%size)[1:]
    for step in steps:
        if not step%size == 0:
            yield step
        else:
            yield size


def pool(method,iters):
    output = []
    p = Pool(4)
    try:
        output = p.map(method,iters)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    finally:
        p.close()
        p.join()
        del p
    return output


def importances(args):
    model, i = args
    y_ = y.copy()
    model.fit(X,y_)
    return model.feature_importances_

n_iters = 100
model_cls = RandomForestClassifier

for batch in draw_batches(n_iters,4):
    print(batch)
    t = time()
    train_args = [(model_cls(n_estimators=50),i) for i in np.arange(batch)]
    imps = pool(importances,train_args)
    print((time()-t)/batch)
```

Though not as pronounced as in the code that I'm working, the above displays that the processing time per model gradually increases the more batches you run. I wouldn't expect this to be the case as the pool processing is all contained and everything is deleted at the end of each run.

What is causing the slow down?

Comment: `RandomForestClassifier` can use multiple cores of cpu - `n_jobs` argument. Try this way and compare running times.

Comment: @Poolka, thanks but the question isn't 'how can I make sklearn.RandomForest run faster' but 'why does the same forest run progressively slower with multiprocessing.Pool'

Comment: @PF1 what operating system are you running on, and what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Jed I'd be interested if your env exhibited the slowdown with a single pool, or whether my guess about making/destroying the pool every time is right

Answer (score 3):

I cannot duplicate a prolonged and continuous increase with the code provided.  Nevertheless, I thought I would present my findings in case they helped.

### Overall time

Piping your script into [`feedgnuplot`](https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot) gives me this runtime (I've removed the division by batch, since the batches are constant in this example, and I wanted to compare time spent in other parts of the code).

[image: overall time]

I apologise for the lack of labelling.  Time in seconds is on the y axis, and the x axis is just batches (hence going to 100/4 = 25).  As you can see, I have lots of variation, but no sustained increase.  (I tried this lots of times with different parameters, but I can't duplicate the sustained increase so I'm giving up).  At no point did I run out of ram or cpu (I have 6 cores, so load was fine).

### Breaking it down

Well: perhaps if I can't duplicate the *problem* I can still figure out what might be going on?  After all, that's a nice juicy bounty...  Here is a horribly unlabelled graph (sorry!):

[image: stages]

I was too lazy to feed line labels in, and I don't know how to add them once I've run gnuplot.  This was produced by modifying your `pool` function like this:

```py
def pool(method, iters):
    start = time()
    output = []
    p = Pool(4)
    pooled = time()
    try:
        output = p.map(method, iters)
        mapped = time()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    finally:
        p.close()
        p.join()
        del p
        ended = time()
    return output, start, pooled, mapped, ended
```

and then outputing the total time running the pool, the time starting the pool, the time running the pool, and the time closing the pool:

```py
processing = time() - t
print(processing, pooled - start, mapped - pooled, ended - mapped)
```

Now (this is why we label things!) The blue line is total time, against the left-hand y axis.  The orange line is pool execution time, against the same axis.  The purple line is time *starting* the pool, against the right-hand y axis, and the green line is time *ending* the pool, against the right-hand y axis.

What we can see from this is that whilst time *running* the pool dominates, time *closing* the pool is proportional to time *running* the pool.  I do not know why this would be: my first guess is garbage collection.

### Another test, to run your end:

What happens if we use one pool?  Does execution slow down? If *I* do this, I get:

[image: pipeline]

I am uncertain exactly what causes the dropoff at the end, but it is reproducible.  This was produced with:

```py
def importances(args):
    start = time()
    model, i = args
    y_ = y.copy()
    model.fit(X, y_)
    return model.feature_importances_, time() - start

n_iters = 100
model_cls = RandomForestClassifier
p = Pool(4)

args = [(model_cls(n_estimators=50), i) for i in np.arange(n_iters)]
outputs = p.map(importances, args)
for _, runtime in outputs:
    print(runtime)
```

This run showed a slight *reduction* in execution/result, but that is purely random.  The increase in runtime/function I attribute to the use of `time()`.

Overall, you are better not batching as the pool can start a new run immediately as soon as one is finished (but you likely knew that).  But I would be interested to know if this also slowed down in your environment.  If so it would disprove the hypothesis that closing the pool is causing the problem.

### Conclusion

I do not consider myself to have answered this question :(  But perhaps we are a little closer to an answer: I speculate that on a machine and under conditions where time *running* the pool starts to blow up, time *closing* the pool will blow up even faster.  Presumably with larger numbers you will start to fragment ram, or even swap, and something like this is causing the increase.  (Just deleting the final object does not always prevent fragmentation, particularly if the intermediate step has used a lot of ram.)

But since I cannot duplicate, I cannot *prove* anything.

### Assumptions

- `time()` is atomic (it isn't)
- alright, then `time()` takes the same amount of time every time

Comment: Just a note on one of your assumptions: `time()` is best effort... it's a python function, so it's not particularly fast itself, and it makes no guarantees of atomicity (clocks between cores on a multi-core cpu can be slightly off) I would assume it's probably accurate enough for a few microseconds, but not nanoseconds (so plenty accurate for something slow running like this...). Special care needs to be taken for ultra accurate timekeeping applications (counting clock cycles...)